# Remove all instances of given object from arraylist of that object

Tags: java

I have these classes:

```
public class class0{
    private ArrayList<class1> array;
    ...
    public void remove(Class1 class1){
        array.remove(class1);
    }
}

public class class1{    
    private Class2 array;
}

public class class2{
    private ArrayList<class1>;
}
```

Is it possible that, when I remove an object of class1 using the given method, automatically deletes that instance from every arraylist that derivates from class1?
(Without going through every list, checking is equals and "remove")

Comment: `private ArrayList<class1>;` this is syntactically wrong in class2

Comment: If you want to remove a specific object from several lists, you have to remove it from each list one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you are doing this:

```
ArrayList<Class1> array = ArrayList<Class1>();

public void add(Class1 class1){
   array.add(class1);
}

public void remove(Class1 class1){
        array.remove(class1);
    }

public static void main(String argv[]){
   Class1 class1 = new Class1();
   Class1 class2 = new Class1();
   new class0.add(class1);
   new class0.add(class2);
   new class0.remove(class1);
}
```

by doing this only array list of class1 object is removed.. and nothing else. class2 object of class1 will still be there and no other lists are deleted

Answer (score 0):

Unless these two lists are the same instance, removal of an element from one list does not impact removal from another list.  You will have to go through each one and remove the element from each.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<'class1> array; // This won't allow anything else but objects of class1

So deleting all objects of class1 is equivalent to clearing the entire array.

If you define: ArrayList array; // without <class1> 
then you can iterate through it and see if entry is of a type by using: 

instanceof 

and then delete it.
```